# what is the use of ClientId in the activemq connectionfactory class

Tags: activemq-classic

Scenario :

```
private readonly IConnection connection;
this.connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
this.connection.ClientId = clientId;
```

Answer (score 2):

The client id is used to logically identify a connection for the purposes of durable subscriptions, and can generally be ignored otherwise. Durable subscriptions allow a client to disconnect/fall over while consuming a topic, and retrieve any messages that it missed when it reconnects. To achieve this, the broker needs this client id to identify which messages are pending consumption. See http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

Although if you want this sort of functionality, a better alternative exists in ActiveMQ in the form of virtual destinations.